# Metapost intersectiontimes

Tags: luatex, metapost

In the code below `intersectiontimes` is not giving an intersection point of the two paths.  Could anyone provide some guidance on how to find (and mark) the intersection points of the curves below?  (I'm a metapost noob, so if you wanted to throw in any other advice, then that would be appreciated as well!)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}

\begin{mplibcode}

gu:=1cm;
vardef j(expr t) = 2*t*t*gu enddef;
vardef g(expr t) = t*t*t*t*gu-2*t*t*gu enddef;

vardef Function(suffix f)(expr ti,tf,n) =
    save fpas;
    fpas := (tf-ti)/n;
    (ti*gu,f(ti)) for i=1 upto n: ..(ti*gu+i*fpas*gu,f(ti+i*fpas)) endfor
enddef;

def mybox(expr l,r,t,b) =
    clip currentpicture to 
    ( (l*gu,b*gu)--(r*gu,b*gu)--(r*gu,t*gu)--(l*gu,t*gu)--cycle)
enddef;

beginfig(1);
    a = -4;
    b = 4;

    path p;
    p = Function(j,a,b,200);

    path q;
    q = Function(g,a,b,200);

    draw p
      yscaled .15
      xscaled .7
      withpen pencircle scaled .5;

    draw q
      yscaled .15
      xscaled .7
      withpen pencircle scaled .5;

    fill buildcycle(reverse(q),p) xscaled .7 yscaled .15 withcolor .7red;

    drawdblarrow ((-2,0)*gu--(2,0)*gu);
    drawdblarrow ((0,-1)*gu--(0,3)*gu) xscaled .7 yscaled .8;

    z1 = (p yscaled .15 xscaled .7) intersectiontimes (q yscaled .15 xscaled .7);
    dotlabel.lft("x",z1);

    mybox(-2,2,-1,2.5);

endfig;
end

\end{mplibcode}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't you want `intersectionpoint`?

Comment: I have no idea what I want!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need `intersectionpoint`; if I change the line

```
z1 = (p yscaled .15 xscaled .7) intersectiontimes (q yscaled .15 xscaled .7);
```

into

```
z1 = (p yscaled .15 xscaled .7) intersectionpoint (q yscaled .15 xscaled .7);
```

I get

[image]

The primitive `intersectiontimes` returns a pair, but its components are two "times": `(t1,t2)`, where `t1` and `t2` are the times when the two paths intersect; so it's not intended for use as a point. Instead, `intersectionpoint` returns the coordinates of the same intersection point.

The rules about the intersections are laid out in section 9.2 of the Metapost manual and in chapter 5 of the METAFONTbook. In this case you can find the intersection at zero with

```
p' = p yscaled .15 xscaled .7; % a couple of shortcuts
q' = q yscaled .15 xscaled .7;

z1 = p' intersectionpoint q'; % find the first intersection
dotlabel.lft("x",z1);

pair meet;
meet = p' intersectiontimes q';
p' := subpath (eps+xpart meet,infinity) of p'; % cut the paths
q' := subpath (eps+ypart meet,infinity) of q';

z2 = p' intersectionpoint q'; % find the second intersection
dotlabel.bot("y",z2);

z3 = (reverse p') intersectionpoint (reverse q'); % find the third intersection
dotlabel.lft("z",z3);
```

The trick of going a bit further with the time that finds (0,0) doesn't work for finding the third point, because it's a minimum on one curve and a maximum on the other. But reversing the path works. However, it would be simpler to find the symmetric point of `z1`, of course.

Comment: Aha!  That was silly of me, thanks egreg :)  A quick question about the intersection at 0...in general, would it find that intersection if my increment (or position of the touching point) was such that when building the path, neither function contained the point `(0,f(0))`?

Comment: Look at section 9.2 of the manual; what among the various intersection points will be chosen is not readily predictable. You have to cut the paths to find the other points (and you can do it with `intersectiontimes`).

Comment: Sorry, I think that was another silly question.  In essence, I was wondering whether metapost is finding the intersections of the approximating paths, or whether it could infer that the functions intersect even if the approximating paths may not (depending on how fine an increment is chosen to build them).  Thus, if the graphs of the functions simply touch one another (and do not cross), then depending on how many points are used to build the approximating paths, metapost might not find that intersection point.  It seems now like that must be the case, is that correct?

Comment: @ScottH. It finds the origin as intersection, as the code I added shows. However, for tangent paths it might not find it, because it works only with discrete increments. At least, this is what I believe: the program is surprising, at times. :)